# Django : NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm having issues with indexing inside reference point in url. I have quite complicated nested object of two raw queries and string inside tuple inside list.

Point is that referencing sometimes works and sometimes does not and I don't really get why.

This piece of html works really well.

```
<td><a href="{% url 'company_info' pair.0.0.0.ticker %}">{{pair.0.0.0.ticker}}</a></td>
```

But this one fails

```
<td><a href="{% url 'company_info' pair.1.0.0.ticker %}">{{pair.1.0.0.ticker}}</a></td>
```

What's more django properly renders this :

```
<td>{{pair.1.0.0.ticker}}</td>
```

But has problem with this one :

```
<a href="{% url 'company_info' pair.1.0.0.ticker %}">
```

Which really indexes the same object. So in one place its ok and in another it fails.

What might be causing that? Sorry if its a little bit messy explanation but html its not really my thing and I might lack some vocabulary.

Comment: Can you try

`{% with pair.1.0.0.ticker as ticker %}

... code that needs ticker goes in between this

{% endwith %}`
I have no idea why it's behaving that weird. Maybe this'll help.

Comment: An example of view and nested object might be really helpful.